# When I am present, most people are quite nervous

Tags: riddle, wordplay

**You could say I am royalty,**

**and when I am present, most people are quite nervous.**

**I have a structure that exhibits a regular repeated pattern of component of parts,**

**much better displayed than my rivals.**

**I roll my eyes at people who have metathesiophobia,**

**and I have my own fan base of people keeping up with me.**

Who am I?

Comment: -**Hint alert**-   Pay very close attention to line five and be sure to keep in mind there could be different forms of the same word as answers in each line. I added the "wordplay" tag for some clarity! :)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Are you a:

> Monarch butterfly

You could say I am royalty,

> Monarch

and when I am present, most people are quite nervous.

> Butterflies are also terrifying

I have a structure that exhibits a regular repeated pattern of component of parts,

> Their wings are pretty and patterned

much better displayed than my rivals.

> Cooler than moths

I roll my eyes at people who have metathesiophobia,

> They do the whole cocoon thing

and I have my own fan base of people keeping up with me.

> Some people keep butterfly gardens intentionally

Comment: HA! beat me by a few seconds cause I had to go look up the spoiler tags. Good Job!

Comment: @Corbin Matheson so close, only a few seconds late! Good job! :)

Comment: are there really people who are terrified of those? (i've never seen or heard of anyone being terrified of those but i guess it could happen?)

Comment: @hanshenrik I think I remember a pop singer when I was a kid said she was terrified of them. I always thought it was funny but I guess people have phobias of all kinds.

Comment: I never knew they could roll their eyes!

Comment: Contains Spoilers, so it is in a Rot13 cipher (thanks to @AniruddhaDeb suggestion!): Lnl! Terng wbo. Lbh ner pbeerpg, gur frpbaq pyhr ersreerq gb univat ohggresyvrf va lbhe fgbznpu naq orvat areibhf, ohg lbh ner evtug ba unun. Jrypbzr gb Chmmyvat Fgnpx Rkpunatr! :Q

Comment: I think the part about being nervous is actually a reference to "having butterflies in your stomach" which is a common saying for being nervous.

Comment: Metathesiophobia probably refers to rot13: gur ohggresyl rssrpg nf zrgngurfvbcubovn vf n srne bs punatr naq gur ohggresyl rssrpg vf n pnfpnqr bs punatrf

Answer (score 39):

Are you:

> COVID-19

*You could say I am royalty,*

> COVID-19 is a coronavirus, corona is from the Latin for crown, often worn by royalty

and when I am present, most people are quite nervous.

> COVID-19 is highly contagious, so people are nervous when it is present nearby

*I have a structure that exhibits a regular repeated pattern of component of parts,*

> The structure of COVID-19 is a highly symmetrical structure built on its parts.
>  [image]]
>  Image credit: Scientificanimations.com

*much better displayed than my rivals.*

> The structure of COVID-19 is now quite well-known and widely available, propogated by scientists and artists alike. We can see here an example of COVID-19 image searches peaking much higher than those of other coronaviruses (rivals) HKU3 and NL63.
>  [image]
>  Manually doing those searches makes it easy to see the hits for COVID-19 on an Image Search or also much more likely to return renditions of its structure/form compared to other coronaviruses.

*I roll my eyes at people who have metathesiophobia,*

> metathesiophobia is the fear of change, something that COVID-19 has caused at a global scale unprecedented in recent years

*and I have my own fan base of people keeping up with me.*

> There are groups across the world trying to track, eradicate, and cope with COVID-19 from [global mayors coming together](https://www.c40.org/other/covid-task-force), [the UN](https://www.who.int/teams/ncds/covid-19/unitaf), to any number of international and national groups, both official and unofficial.

Comment: This is a very good guess, but I am afraid it is incorrect! Keep guessing! :D

Comment: I am surprised this is incorrect. I wonder for which line of the riddle is this answer a bit too much of a reach, or if it's an alternate answer unintended by the poster?

Comment: I thought it was a really good answer, but not the intended answer and line five is a bit of a reach, but it almost fit haha. Points for creativity!

Comment: This was my first thought too, a great alternate answer, even if not what Crozier intended!

Comment: Gonna have to check out scientificanimations.com :)

Answer (score 9):

Are you a:

> Queen Bee

You could say I am royalty,

> A Queen Bee is the queen of the bees!

and when I am present, most people are quite nervous.

> People are scared of bees

I have a structure that exhibits a regular repeated pattern of component of parts,

> The hexagonal honeycombs in beehives

much better displayed than my rivals.

> Bee colonies probably have rivalries with each other

I roll my eyes at people who have metathesiophobia,

> Not really sure, but queen bees do sometimes move away in difficult times to form a new colony

and I have my own fan base of people keeping up with me.

> Attendant bees take care of the queen bee. And probably the rest of the colony is a 'fanbase'

Comment: Good guess @Bryan C, but focus very hard on the line about metathesiophobia. So far you are very close to the real answer! :)

Comment: For this answer, re: line 5, the queen (and all bees) "do the whole cocoon thing" almost identically to butterflies, just a bit faster and without living in larvae (caterpillar) stage as long - no less of a metamorphosis though. Just FYI for anyone reading

Answer (score 5):

> Monarch butterfly

You could say I am royalty,

> its right in the name

and when I am present, most people are quite nervous.

> people freak out around butterflys

I have a structure that exhibits a regular repeated pattern of component of parts,

> wings have a repeating pattern

much better displayed than my rivals.

> generaly much more vibrant then moths

I roll my eyes at people who have metathesiophobia,

> metamorphasis

and I have my own fan base of people keeping up with me.

> people track them

Answer (score 4):

Are you a:

> Regal Moth

You could say I am royalty,

> Regal

and when I am present, most people are quite nervous.

> Moths are terrifying

I have a structure that exhibits a regular repeated pattern of component of parts,

> Their wings are pretty and patterned

much better displayed than my rivals.

> Eaten by bats and owls, neither of which have equally cool wing patterns

I roll my eyes at people who have metathesiophobia,

> They do the whole cocoon thing

and I have my own fan base of people keeping up with me.

> There's also a talk show called The Moth that people keep up with that has a big fan base?

Comment: You are SUPER close! Very, very close, you almost have it. What is the commonly said opposite of the moth? @iamjane

Comment: I added another answer- I thought this one fit more because of the bits about making people nervous and having a fan base

Comment: Impressive! This does fit better than the actual intended answer.

Answer (score 3):

You could be

> Goose Bumps

You could say I am royalty,

> According to [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Goosebumps), The Goosebumps book series is the second bestselling of all time behind the Harry Potter series

and when I am present, most people are quite nervous.

> People can get goose bumps when they are very nervous

I have a structure that exhibits a regular repeated pattern of component of parts,

> Goose bumps are a regular pattern of raised pores on the skin

much better displayed than my rivals.

> Apes and other animals use goosebumps to raise their fir when being defensive or showing visual dominance

I roll my eyes at people who have metathesiophobia,

> Those who like change may like the thrills of getting goose bumps?

and I have my own fan base of people keeping up with me.

> Thrill seekers?

Comment: Good answer @MacGyver88, but I am afraid it is incorrect!

Answer (score 2):

You could be

> Time

You could say I am royalty,

> One of the scarce things nowadays. You should be a royal adult to have enough.

when I am present, most people are quite nervous

> People do stay nervous sometimes, which makes them to be nervous at present.

I have a structure that exhibits a regular repeated pattern of component of parts

> We have structured time into, seconds, minutes, hours etc

much better displayed than my rivals.

> Present is always clearly visible than future or past. (Would like if someone can improve this argument)

I roll my eyes at people who have metathesiophobia,

> Time punishes the people who don't get changed with time

and I have my own fan base of people keeping up with me.

> Time rewards those who gets changed with time.

Comment: Good guess @Pandey_Ji, but I am afraid you are incorrect!

Answer (score 2):

You could say I am royalty,

and when I am present, most people are quite nervous

Perhaps you are

> A shark.Naturally fish or human would feel nervous in the presence of a shark

I have a structure that exhibits a regular repeated pattern of component of parts,

much better displayed than my rivals

> The dinstictive shape of teeth a shark has

I roll my eyes at people who have metathesiophobia

> I suppose that movements attract a shark's attention

and I have my own fan base of people keeping up with me.

> Many species of fish follow a shark and have a symbiotic relation with him.